# Improved Bernoulli's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Applying the first theorem from [this paper](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jmi-03-21.pdf) directly to the function $(1+x)^r$, with $0<r<1$ and $r$ rational (strictly speaking), I was able to show this refinement of Bernoulli's Inequality
$$(1+x)^r\leq 1+rx-r(1-r)(\sqrt{1+x}-1)^2$$
when $r$ lies between $0$ and $1$ (we use continuity to extend this result to irrationals) and for $x\geq -1$. Besides being quite sharp, this inequality also wraps up the case of equality in the more canonical Bernoulli's Inequality.

> Naturally, this result begs to have a dual proved. That is, can we
>   find a function $f$ and a constant $C_r$ such that $$(1+x)^r\geq 1+rx+C_r(f(x))^2$$ where $r>1$, $x\geq -1$, $C_r>0$ is allowed to
>   depend on $r$, and $f$ has a unique root at $0$?

The thought that occurred to me was to choose the positive integer $n$ such that $n-1\leq r<n$ and then apply the previous result to
$$\left(1+\frac{r}{n}x\right)^{n/r}=\left(1+\frac{r}{n}x\right)^{(n-1)/r}\left(1+\frac{r}{n}x\right)^{1/r}$$
and hopefully take powers and apply the integer form of Bernoulli to the left-hand side. The algebra have proved tedious and subtle however.

I've thought about trudging through the Taylor Formula for $(1+x)^r$ (Newton's binomial expansion), but the case analysis on $r$ and $x$ doesn't seem fruitful or pretty.

Comment: I might remark that it is easy to show that $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx+(n-1)x^2$ for integer $n$. There are a couple nuances that we begin to stumble upon when we try to show $(1+x)^r\geq 1+rx+(r-1)x^2$, particularly for $1<r<2$. Although not a requirement, I would like to see the $C_r$ not depend on the interval that $r$ lies in.

Comment: $(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}x^3+....+nx^{n-1}$ for $n>1, x \ge 0$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "interval that $r$ lies in"

Comment: @CốGắngLên the interesting case is when we consider $-1\leq x<0$.

Comment: @zhw For $r\geq 2$ we can show that $(1+x)^r\geq 1+rx+(r-1)x^2$ but difficulties arise when we attempt to show the same for $1<r<2$ and there isn't actually a $C_r$ which will satisfy $(1+x)^r\geq 1+rx+C_r x^2$ for all $x\geq -1$.

Comment: @Robert Apparently you let this expire without giving out the bounty. Any reason?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there are too many such $f$'s. Let's look at one of them: Define $f(x) = x^2/(1+x^2).$ Important properties of this function: $f(x) =O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0,$ and $|f|<1$ everywhere.

Claim: For any $r>1$ there exists $C_r>0$ such that

$$(1+x)^r \ge 1 + rx + C_rf(x)^2$$

for all $x\in [-1,\infty).$

Proof: Let $r>1.$ Then $(1+x)^r = 1 + rx + r(r-1)x^2/2 + O(x^3)$ as $x \to 0.$ Thus there exists $a, 0<a<1,$ such that

$$\tag 1 (1+x)^r \ge 1 + rx + r(r-1)x^2/4$$

for $x\in [-a,a].$ Note that $f(x)^2 \le x^4.$ Choose $b,0<b<a$ such that

$$\tag 2 r(r-1)x^2/4\ge x^4$$

for $x\in [-b,b].$ At this point, by $(1)$ and $(2),$ we know

$$(1+x)^r \ge 1 + rx + f(x)^2,\,\, x\in [-b,b].$$

Now $(1+x)^r - (1 + rx)$ has a positive minimum $m$ on $[-1,-b]\cup [b,\infty).$ Thus for $x\in [-1,-b]\cup [b,\infty),$

$$\tag 3(1+x)^r \ge 1 + rx + m \ge 1 + rx + mf(x)^2,$$

where here we used $|f|<1.$ Setting $C_r = \min(1,m),$ we see $(1),(2),(3)$ prove the claim.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove the following:

> If $f:[-1,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a strictly concave and strictly increasing function, with one single root, $f(0)=0$, and $f\in C^1((-1,+\infty))$, then there exists a $C_r>0$ such that:
>   $$(1+x)^r\geq1+rx+C_r(f(x))^2$$
>   for every $x\geq-1$, $r>1$.

**Proof:** Let
$$G(x)=(1+x)^r-1-rx-C_r(f(x))^2,\ x\geq-1$$
We need to prove that $G(x)\geq0$ for every $x\geq-1$ and $r>1$. For this purpose, let $r>1$. To choose $C_r$ we note that:
$$G(x)\geq0\Leftrightarrow C_r\leq\frac{(1+x)^r-1-rx}{(f(x))^2}:=g(x),\ \forall x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$$
since $G(0)=0$ and the result can expand to $x_0=-1$ due to continuity of $G$. Since the above inequality holds for every $x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$, it follows that:
$$C_r\leq\inf_{x>-1\\ x\neq0}g(x)$$
To continue, we will prove the following

**Lemma:** If $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, bounded below, with $A\cap B=\varnothing$, and $f(x):A\cup B\to\mathbb{R}$ then:
$$\inf_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)=\min\left\{\inf_{x\in A}f(x),\inf_{x\in B}f(x)\right\}$$

*Proof:* Since $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$, it is immediate that $\inf\limits_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)\leq\min\left\{\inf\limits_{x\in A}f(x),\inf\limits_{x\in B}f(x)\right\}$.

To prove the inverse inequality, let us suppose that:
$$\inf_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)<\min\left\{\inf_{x\in A}f(x),\inf_{x\in B}f(x)\right\}$$
So $\inf\limits_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)<\inf\limits_{x\in A}f(x)$ and, hence, there exist a $x\in A\cup B\setminus A\overset{A\cap B=\varnothing}{=}B$, such that 
$$f(x)<\inf_{z\in A}f(z)$$
In the same way, we can find a $y\in A$, such that:
$$f(y)<\inf_{z\in B}f(z)\leq f(x)<\inf_{z\in A}f(z)$$
which is a contradiction, since $\inf\limits_{z\in A}f(z)$ is a lower bound for $A$. Hence
$$\inf_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)\geq\min\left\{\inf_{x\in A}f(x),\inf_{x\in B}f(x)\right\}$$
which completes the proof of our lemma.

Continuing to our proof, we can now write:
$$C_r\leq\min\left\{\inf_{x\in(-1,0)}g(x),\inf_{x\in(0,+\infty)}g(x)\right\}$$

We now consider the following cases:

1. If $x>0$, then, due to $f$'s monotonicity, we have:
   $$x>0\overset{f:\uparrow}{\Rightarrow}f(x)>f(0)=0\Rightarrow f(x)>0$$
   Also, due to $f$'s concavity, we have that $f'$ is strictly decreasing over $(-1,+\infty)$. Also, since $f$ is strictly increasing we have that $f'(x)\geq0$ for every $x\in(-1,+\infty)$ and, since, $f'$ is strictly decreasing, it comes as a result that $f'(x)>0$ for every $x>-1$. We will now prove that $\frac{1}{(f(x))^2}$ is both strictly convex and strictly decreasing.

*Monotonicity:* Let $x_1,x_2\in(0,+\infty)$ with $x_1<x_2$. Then:
$$x_1<x_2\Rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)\overset{f>0}{\Rightarrow}(f(x_1))^2<(f(x_2))^2\Rightarrow\frac{1}{(f(x_1))^2}>\frac{1}{(f(x_2))^2}$$
which is what has been requested.

*Convexity:* Let $x,y\in(0,+\infty)$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$. Then, beginning with $f$'s concavity, we get:
$$\begin{align*}
&f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)>\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow&\frac{1}{f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)}<\frac{1}{\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)}\overset{\frac{1}{x}\text{ is convex}}{<}\lambda\frac{1}{f(x)}+(1-\lambda)\frac{1}{f(y)}\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow&\frac{1}{(f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y))^2}<\left(\lambda\frac{1}{f(x)}+(1-\lambda)\frac{1}{f(y)}\right)^\overset{x^2\text{ is convex}}{<}\lambda\frac{1}{(f(x))^2}+(1-\lambda)\frac{1}{(f(y))^2}
\end{align*}$$
which is what has been requested.

We will now prove another

**Lemma:** If $a:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ and $b:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ are two differentiable functions with $a$ being both strictly increasing and convex and $b$ both strictly decreasing and convex, with $a(0)=a'(0)=0$, then $ab$ is increasing.

*Proof:* We note that:

$$(ab(x))'=a'(x)b(x)+a(x)b'(x)\geq a'(0)b(x)+a(0)b'(x)=0$$
since $a$'s convexity inplies that $a'$ is strictly increasing and, hence $a(x)\geq a(0)=0$ and $a(x)\geq a(0)$ since $a$ is strictly increasing, for every $a\geq0$.

So, since $(ab)'\geq0$ it is immediate that $ab$ is increasing.

Now, let $a(x)=(1+x)^r-1-rx$ and $b(x)=\frac{1}{(f(x))^2}$. It is easy to verify that the conditions of our lemma are satisfied, so $ab$ is increasing. Note now that:
$$g(x)=a(x)b(x)$$
so, we get that:
$$\begin{align*}\inf_{x>0}g(x)=&\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)=\\
=&\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(1+x)^r-1-rx}{(f(x))^2}\overset{\text{d. L'H.}}{=}\\
=&\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{r(1+x)^{r-1}-r}{2f(x)f'(x)}=\\
=&\frac{1}{f'(0)}\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{r(1+x)^{r-1}-r}{f(x)}\overset{\text{d. L'H.}}{=}\\
=&\frac{1}{f'(0)}\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{r(r-1)(1+x)^{r-2}}{f'(x)}=\\
=&\frac{r(r-1)}{2(f'(0))^2}
\end{align*}$$
So:
$$\inf_{x>0}f(x)\leq\frac{r(r-1)}{2(f'(0))^2}$$

2. If $-1<x<0$, then, due to $f$'s monotonicity, we get:
   $$-1<x<0\Rightarrow f(-1)<f(x)<f(0)=0\Rightarrow(f(-1))^2>(f(x))^2$$
   so:
   $$g(x)=\frac{(1+x)^r-1-rx}{(f(x))^2}\geq\frac{(1+x)^r-1-rx}{(f(-1))^2}$$
   so, taking infima over the two sides of the above inequality, we get:
   $$\inf_{x\in(-1,0)}\geq\inf_{x\in(-1,0)}\frac{(1+x)^r-1-rx}{(f(-1))^2}=\lim_{x\to-1^+}\frac{(1+x)^r-1-rx}{(f(-1))^2}=\frac{r-1}{(f(-1))^2}$$
   So, we can choose a tighter bound for $C_r$, than $\inf\limits_{-1<x<0}f(x)$, which is $\frac{r-1}{(f(-1))^2}$

Finally, we have that:
$$C_r\leq\min\left\{\frac{r-1}{(f(-1))^2},\frac{r(r-1)}{2(f'(0))^2}\right\}$$

Some examples might be:

1. $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}-1$ with $C_r=r-1$,
2. $f(x)=\ln(2+x)-\ln2$ with $C_r=r-1$,
3. $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+x}-1$ with $C_r=r-1$ etc.

**Notes**

- In order to lighten our conditions, $f$ can be concave only over $[0,+\infty)$, since in case 2 we made use only of $f$'s monotonicity.
- It is clear that the strong hypothesis is concavity, since it directly implies continuity everywhere and differentiability almost everywhere 
  (however this is not something relevant to this proof, so we shall omit it).
- The existence of $C_r$ ensures that the inequality holds for every $r>1$. If we choose, for example $C_r=1$, then, for every function $f$ 
  that satisfies the given conditions, there exist an $r_0=r_0(f)\geq1$ such that our inequation holds for every $r>r_0$. To prove this, we note 
  that, it is sufficient that the following is true:
  $$1\leq\min\left\{\frac{r-1}{(f(-1))^2},\frac{r(r-1)}{2(f'(0))^2}\right\}$$
  So, chosing - the solution is trivial, so we omit it:
  $$r_0=\max\left\{(f(-1))^2+1,\frac{1+\sqrt{1+8(f'(0))^2}}{2}\right\}$$
  ensures that for every $r\geq r_0$, the inequality holds.

Comment: I think you made a mistake somewhere. Let $f(x) = x +\ln (1+x/2).$ Then $f$ satisfies your hypotheses. However, if $1<r<2,$ then $(1+x)^r$ is on the order of $x^r$ for $x$large, while if $C>0,$ $Cf(x)^2$ is on the order of $x^2.$